# Java Tabbed Pane: display an icon close on the title

Tags: java, swing

it is possible to show an icon "X" on the title of the tab, used to close the tab ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest looking over the tutorial of, [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) and scroll down to the section entitled *Tabs With Custom Components*.

Also if you look at the [*example index*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TabComponentsDemo) link inside that section, the sample code is given.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just created an implementation of this myself. :)

Something like this:

```
/* These need to be final so you can reference them in the MouseAdapter subclass
 * later. I personally just passed them to a method to add the tab, with the
 * parameters marked as final.
 * i.e., public void addCloseableTab(final JTabbedPane tabbedPane, ...)
 */
final Component someComponent = ...; //Whatever component is being added
final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
//I had my own subclass of AbstractButton, but that's irrelevant in this case
JButton closeButton = new JButton("x");

/*
 * titlePanel is initialized containing a JLabel with the tab title, 
 * and closeButton. (I don't recall the tabbed pane showing a title itself after 
 * setTabComponentAt() is called)
 */
JPanel titlePanel = ...;
tabbedPane.add(someComponent);
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(tabbedPane.indexOfComponent(someComponent), titlePanel);

closeButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        tabbedPane.remove(someComponent);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Oh, and a possible downside, setTabComponentAt() is only available as of Java 6... so this won't work in earlier versions.